# How to programmatically lay out stacking views and rotate?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, autolayout

I'd like to layout 3 imageViews programmatically by setting the frames manually. I am able to set up the middle image just fine but when trying to rotate the other two, the images's frames distort when using CGAffineTransform(rotatedBy:)

Right now I am setting the center image based on the center of the view and using that as a reference point for the left and right images. Any suggestions to rotate the images or if there's anything glaringly wrong with my approach? I suspect the issue has to do with the rotating point when using CGAffineTransform. I read around and folks say it's defaulted at (0,0) and I believe I want to rotate the images individually around their center point?

Also is there a way to keep the aspect ratio and scale the images with a larger view? Right now, the height and width are fixed.

*note I left out the code to load images as it not relevant to the question.

[image]

```
  public final class PhotosView: UIView {
    private let rightImageViewWidth: CGFloat = 98.0
    private let rightImageViewHeight: CGFloat = 128.0
    private let centerImageViewWidth: CGFloat = 128.0
    private let centerImageViewHeight: CGFloat = 174.0
    private let leftImageViewWidth: CGFloat = 98.0
    private let leftImageViewHeight: CGFloat = 128.0
    private let verticlePadding: CGFloat = 28.0

    private var leftImageView: UIImageView

    private var centerImageView: UIImageView

    private var rightImageView: UIImageView

    public init(frame: CGRect) {
      self.leftImageView = UIImageView()
      self.centerImageView = UIImageView()
      self.rightImageView = UIImageView()
      super.init(frame: frame)

      self.addSubview(self.rightImageView)

      self.addSubview(self.centerImageView)

      self.addSubview(self.leftImageView)
    }
    required init(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("Not implemented") }

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
      let bounds = self.bounds
      self.centerImageView.frame = CGRect(
        x: bounds.midX - (centerImageViewWidth / 2.0), y: self.verticlePadding,
        width: self.centerImageViewWidth,
        height: self.centerImageViewHeight)

      self.rightImageView.frame = CGRect(
        x: self.centerImageView.frame.maxX - self.largePadding,
        y: self.centerImageView.frame.minY + self.largePadding,
        width: self.rightImageViewWidth,
        height: self.rightImageViewHeight)

      self.leftImageView.frame = CGRect(
        x: self.centerImageView.frame.minX - self.leftImageViewWidth + self.largePadding,
        y: self.centerImageView.frame.minY + self.largePadding, width: self.leftImageViewWidth,
        height: self.leftImageViewHeight)
    }

    public override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
      super.sizeThatFits(size)
      let height = (2.0 * self.verticlePadding) + self.centerImageView.frame.height
      return CGSize(width: size.width, height: height)
    }
```

Comment: Is the image in your question what you see or what you want to see ? I see the word stack in your question but just confirming, you are not working with stack views ?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this article: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1702-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-a-spinning-wheel